# Embed reactjs app with access to localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, brave

I have a Reactjs app that uses localstorage, I would like users to be able to embed my website.

I would like to access the localstorage for my website when it is embedded, but **I get the following message twice:**

> **DOMException:** Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

I also use the localstorage when users use my website normally.

**How can I check localstorage** of my own website when it is being embedded via iframe?

Preferrably I would like to know how I can do it within the realm of reactjs, worst case, I can just never check local storage and they can login from the embed.

If it is impossible, would I be able to check cookies via react in an iframe?

Comment: When you embed a website into another, usually you get limited access to the underlying JS engine. The error you are getting indicates that the JS engine running in the embedding service/medium you are using does not support `localStorage`, therefore, you cannot use `localStorage` for a React app running in that context (embedded into wherever you are getting this error)

Comment: I get this error when I embed it on a plain index.html file and when I host it through nodejs as well.

Comment: You were correct. I was using Brave browser and I needed to put all the shields down. I wasted like 3 hours implementing cookies only to eventually realize I never tried a different browser or turning off the shields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using brave, you must "allow all cookies" enabled, or cross-site cookies will be blocked. An embed accessing localStorage is considered cross-site cookie in this case and will be blocked, so you can try to access local storage and if you get that error your app knows it is in an embed.